# ASMX webservice doesn't serialize part of objects

Tags: .net, asmx, dynamics-crm-2015

I develop ASMX proxy webservice that is used with JS from a portal. All that webservice is doing is calling other webservice and returns data to a caller. This is done to revoke cross-domain JS calls.

Here is the code of my webservice:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public EntityCollection GetEnterpriseProducts(string entityName, string id)
    {
        OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest()
        {
            RequestName = "dot_GetEnterpriseProducts"
        };
        request["EntityType"] = entityName;
        request["EntityId"] = id;

        var response = GetService().Execute(request);

        return (EntityCollection)response.Results["Products"];
    }
```

When I debug code I see that returned result is correct and contains valid data. But when call is done from JS for some reason part of data disappears. Here is what I get after the call:

[image: Result from fiddler]

If that could help I call CRM 2015 endpoint to get the data.

Comment: (What is "dot_GetEnterpriseProducts" ?) If you invoke the same call in browser is data correct ?

Comment: dot_GetEnterpriseProducts is Action (if you familiar with Dynamics CRM). Data looks the same if I both call webservice from HTML/JS or .Net app so seems that the result is incorrectly serialized. Looking for a way to override standard serialization.

Comment: I concur that the asmx seems to be the culprit, unfortunately I don't know enough about asmx to provide a meaningful answer (other than "build viewmodels for the data and (de)serialize it yourself" which I'd anyway keep as a last-est resort...)

Comment: @Alex you were 100% right. Thanks for a hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer - don't use old-style dying ASMX webservices. Everything worked once I replaces ASMX webservice with WCF endpoint. Serialization works fine there.